# ubuntu 14.04 docker issues

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'am getting the error below, nothing has changed in the last 24-48 hrs.

Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/14.04: unauthorized: incorrect username or password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do below

```
mv ~/.docker/config.json ~/.docker/config.json.old
```

Run

```
docker login
```

And authenticate again to generate new tokens. Then things should work